# how can I avoid Black screen between activities because of hard load on onCreate activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, oncreate

I have a splash screen that waits 2 seconds and invokes the main activity which is a dashboard that retrieves and calculates a lot of data from a database.
The issue is that a long lasting black-screen is displayed between the 2 activities (after the 2 seconds of the splash screen), and the user should wait for the 2nd activity to be displayed, because the activity is doing a lot of stuff before showing up.
Is there a straightforward solution to avoid the hard work on the onCreate method.

Comment: use any **material loader** at start of 2nd activity and show message like **loading data.. please wait**

Comment: Ali could you please suggest a code for that. I mean when I should create the material loader and when the real activity show up ?

Comment: Post relevant parts of your code so we can have a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: You can put the hard work in a background thread. This will also avoid the "application not responding" errors if loading takes more than 5 seconds (maybe on older devices)

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the data and do the calculation in SplashActivity itself, by doing that you won't have to make user wait for 2 seconds earlier and again while fetching data. You can send that results to the next activity to display it but as what calculations are happening is not mentioned this may or may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a `ProgressBar` while the `database` activity is going on, since `database` stuff is designed to run in background thread, it is a good practice to introduce a kind of `interactivity` such as indeterminate `ProgressBar` etc so that the user will `understand` some sort of operation is being performed before interacting with the `UI`.

Another way to look into it is to ensure you are not running threads that should run in the `background` on the `UI thread` because this will lock the `UI` and this is not a good practice.....